# ogr2ogr styling of KML point features

Tags: kml, ogr2ogr

Using ogr2ogr I want to export tables from a PostGIS database as KML-files. I have succesfully used an "OGR_STYLE"-column/attribute on my line features to define line width and color, see: http://www.gdal.org/ogr_feature_style.html

An example of a line styling could be: PEN(c:#b3ff00,w:2.5px) - when using ogr2ogr this styling is applied to the output KML feature when displayed in Google Earth.

However, when I try to use this kind of styling for my point features (e.g. SYMBOL(c:#00FF00,id:"points.sym-45,ogr-sym-7") ), the default marker and color is displayed when opening the KML-file in Google Earth.

Is there any way to get this custom styling to work when exporting point features to KML?

Answer (score 0):

Example with "shaded_dot" KML style

```
set icon="http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/shaded_dot.png"
set rgba150="#00FF00"

SYMBOL(c:%rgba150%,id:"%icon%")
```

or

```
   SYMBOL(c:#00FF00,id:"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/shaded_dot.png")
```

So, resulted style definition in KML file will be:

```
  <Placemark id="points_test.4">
    <Style>
      <IconStyle>
        <color>ff00ffff</color>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/shaded_dot.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
    </Style>
```